# What would be the easiest way to obtain a list of article-categories relation from Wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia

I am speaking specifically for the English version of wikipedia (enwiki). I tried this for other lighter version of Wikipedia by downloading sql dumps (categorylinks, page, page_prop) but with the English version this is not easily done. I am writing the data from the sql files into a database at the moment, but I would like some other and easier way to do that, since this will take a lot of time. And if I actually succeed writing the data, the query will probably take forever. So, how could I compile a list of articles and their categories from the English Wikipedia?

Comment: if I understand correctly you want to retrieve pages from wikipedia e.g. `Albert Einstein`, and get also the page category, etc? you may want to use the Wikipedia API: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&prop=categories&titles=Albert%20Einstein

Comment: I tried using the ApiSandBox but from what I gather the Api has a limit of 500 records, right? The number of articles is 4 - 5.000.000.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no easy answer to this. Downloading and using the dumps isn't very approachable with conventional computers. Thankfully there is a service that I used called [Quarry](https://quarry.wmflabs.org), that let's you query the Wikipedia databases. However there are limitations, so in order to get the above list I had to cut my queries into smaller pieces using the `limit clause` and giving the same query +50 times. To anyone wanting this data, can visit my [quarry profile](https://quarry.wmflabs.org/Mmaarrkkooss) and obtain the data from the `Article - Categories` queries.